# Moment.js - Calculate Day Count - Exclude weekdays

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

## Situation

- I need to calculate the day count between two dates
- Not all days are counted, only given days (e.g. monday, thursday, friday)
- The list of given days is variable
- The list if a `boolean[]` of the size `7`, whereas each position in the array will have the value `true` if the weekday should be counted, `false` else
- The position `0` in the array is sunday, `1` is monday ... `6` is saturday

## Approach

Currently I have an iterative solution:

```js
function countDays(dateStart, dateEnd, includedDays) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let m = moment(dateStart); m.diff(dateEnd, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    if (includedDays[m.weekday()]) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

let count = countDays(moment({
    year: 2018,
    month: 1,
    day: 1
  }),
  moment({
    year: 2018,
    month: 1,
    day: 14
  }), [false, true, true, false, true, false, false]);
console.log('Daycount: ' + count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

## Question

For big differences this approach of course takes some seconds to complete.
Does someone have an idea for a more performant solution?

Thank you already!

Comment: I suggest to calculate the amount of complete weeks between the 2 dates and multiply that with the amount of `true` in your array. Of course you must then also add the remaining days of the last incomplete week with your own logic.

Comment: You should take a look to this `momentjs` plugin: https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur It helps creating interval for which you can set which day is counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of [Thomas Kleßen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4629808) to use the weeks between the dates I implemented a solution on my own.

The code uses the iterative approach for the first & last week in the range, but uses the week count for everything in between:

```js
function countDaysIterative(dateStart, dateEnd, includedDays) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let m = moment(dateStart); m.diff(dateEnd, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    if (includedDays[m.weekday()]) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

function countDays(dateStart, dateEnd, includedDays) {
  let weekCount = dateEnd.diff(dateStart, 'weeks');

  switch (weekCount) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      return countDaysIterative(dateStart, dateEnd, includedDays);
    default:
      let firstWeekEnd = moment(dateStart).endOf('week');
      let lastWeekStart = moment(dateEnd).startOf('week');
      let firstWeekDayCount = countDaysIterative(dateStart, firstWeekEnd, includedDays);
      let lastWeekDayCount = countDaysIterative(lastWeekStart, dateEnd, includedDays);
      let subWeekCount = lastWeekStart.diff(firstWeekEnd, 'weeks');
      let daysPerWeekCount = includedDays.filter(v => v).length;
      return (subWeekCount * daysPerWeekCount) + firstWeekDayCount + lastWeekDayCount;
  }
}

let start = moment({
  year: 2018,
  month: 1,
  day: 1
});
let end = moment({
  year: 2018,
  month: 1,
  day: 21
});
let includedDays = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false];

console.log('Daycount: ' + countDays(start, end, includedDays));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here: the month index of moment.js is 0 based, so the shown dates are for february. And there the end date is correctly included as far as I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `recur` plugin of `momentjs` which can be found here: https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur

You will have to create an interval between the `start` and the `end` dates.
The `includedDays` is transformed to have the `daysToInclude`:

- `map` function returns `-1` if the current item in the array is `false`. It returns the `index` if the current `item` is `true`. Knowing that index `0` is `sunday`.
- `filter` function gets only the values which are greater or equal than `0`

Then, the `recurrence` is created between `start` and `end` for every `daysToInclude` days of weeks.

The `count` is obtained by getting `all` the matching days and taking the `length` of the resulting array.

```js
let start = moment({ year: 2018, month: 1, day: 1 });
let end = moment({ year: 2018, month: 1, day: 14 });
let includedDays = [false, true, true, false, true, false, false];

let daysToInclude = includedDays.map((item, idx) => item ? idx : -1)
  .filter(item => item >= 0);
  
let recurrence = moment().recur(start, end)
  .every(daysToInclude).daysOfWeek();
 
console.log('Days count: ' + recurrence.all().length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-recur/1.0.7/moment-recur.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found a solution that works out without the use of the plugin. Your idea looks good anyways!